# Is there a Python container that acts like a dictionary but doesn't need both key and value?

Tags: python

Say I have:

```py
@dataclass
class Foo:
  foo_id: int
  # Other interesting fields.

  def __hash__(self):
    return self.foo_id.__hash__()
```

And I make a `foos_set = {Foo(i) for i in range(10)}`. I had always assumed that `set.remove` used the hash for constant-time lookup. So I thought it would be reasonable to think that `foos_set.remove(6)` should work. But actually, it raises a `KeyError`. You'd need to do `foo_set.remove(Foo(6))`. In fact, if there are more fields, you need to make sure that all of them match!

I suppose the right thing for me to do is just make a `foos_dict = {i: Foo(i) for i in range(10)}`. And I'd be happy to do that, but it just feels unnecessarily clunky so here I am asking if there's another container I don't know about.

Comment: I'm confused.  If you have a set of `Foo`s and you want to remove a `Foo`, why wouldn't you *not* use a `Foo` to remove it in constant time, unless you wanted to search the entire collection for it?  Maybe the `set` is the problem and you should be keen on `list` instead since you can't guarantee constant removal if you have to search for it?

Comment: `Foo(6)` isn't equal to `6`, so why should `.remove(6)` do anything with it?  All you've done by defining `__hash__()` alone is to create a hash collision between those two values.  Define `__eq__()` as well, so that `Foo(6)` actually *is* equal to `6`, and your set should work.

Comment: @jasonharper I thought that might be it. So a lookup uses a hash to find the element, then it uses equality to verify it. Didn't know about the second part.

Comment: calling `<int>.__hash__()` will give you the same value. That method does not make sense for your input

Comment: @Makoto actually I was just giving an example. In my code I do remove with Foo, but I wanted to also be able to retrieve an element from the set using just  the ID (without having to do a search).

Comment: The second part is absolutely necessary, as hash collisions are unavoidable in general.

Comment: Alexander and Jason: You might be talking past each other. I honestly believe that `foo_set.remove(Foo(6))` is already just fine, because *of course* a set containing `Foo(6)` will use the hash of `Foo(6)`.

Comment: @LoverofStructure maybe it seems we are talking past each other because my question feels a bit odd in retrospect. Jason's comment about hash collisions and needing an equality check pretty much answers to me why it wouldn't make sense for my proposed data structure to exist.

Comment: @AlexanderSoare Using the hash of `Foo(6)` doesn't require lookup per se. I assume that you might have `Foo(6)` stored somewhere else, say in `somefoo`. If you then delete it from the set, the set will compute the hash of `somefoo`. In the *unlikely* event of a hash collision, lookup will be slightly slower, but nothing will otherwise go wrong. But Jason is correct in that you wouldn't want to make a set with both `Foo(index)` and `index` in the same set (due to the resulting guaranteed hash collisions).

Comment: Using a dictionary here is not "clunky". The point of a dictionary is that it is a *map*, which is exactly what you need here.

Comment: Anyway, the problem seems to be that that you thought that a hash-based container determines whether two objects are equivalent *by hashing*. It doesn't, it is a combination of hash + equality check.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yep the last bit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### If you want to be able to jump to and delete a particular entry based on an id, use a dictionary

A dictionary is *par excellence* a container that is indexed by a specific piece of information - the key.

A set is, in effect, indexed on the whole entry, not just the key. A list is indexed on something that is not part of the entry itself, but rather its position in the list.

So

```
foos_dict = {i: Foo(i) for i in range(10)}
```

is in fact the perfect way to achieve what you want.

#### This *proves* that you need a dictionary!

You are literally describing a dictionary:

> I wanted to also be able to retrieve an element from the set using just the ID (without having to do a search).